# how can i find the contract name from the address using the etherscan API?

Tags: ether, etherscan

I have the address but I want to know the name of contract. Is there any way to get that from the etherscan API?

Answer (score 2):

There is no special API method to get the name of contract. But if you are talking about ERC20 Tokens, you can try another method [BETA]:

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2&page=1&offset=5

It returns ERC20 token transfer events for a specific contract. So you can extract required information `"tokenName":"Maker","tokenSymbol":"MKR"` from the response.

Answer (score 1):

`getsourcecode` Etherscan API endpoint returns the name of a contract. You can find the description of the endpoint here: https://etherscan.io/apis#contracts

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address=0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

It returns `` in the resulting JSON:

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "message": "OK",
    "result": [{
        ...,
        "ContractName": "..."
    }]
}
```

It should be mentioned, that this API will return contract name only if the contract has been verified.

Comment: Doesn't work for the most contracts, e.g.` https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address=0xcb0c5d9d92f4f2f80cce7aa271a1e148c226e19d&apikey=YourApiKey` vs https://etherscan.io/address/0xcb0c5d9d92f4f2f80cce7aa271a1e148c226e19d#code

Comment: @shredding It will work only for contracts, that have been verified on Etherscan (I updated my answer with the note at the bottom). You providing the example of the contract which has not been verified directly, but Etherscan did found verified bytecode clone. Take a look to the note on the 2nd link, you provided `Note: This contract matches the deployed ByteCode of the Source Code for Contract 0x8f8ef111b67c04eb164...`. If you request source code from contract `0x8f83...` getsourcecode API endpoint will return contract name.